# jQuery Json + jQuery onChange

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am using php to talk to a mysql database then encoding the associative array with json_encode.  That much I know is working, I can call the php directly and see the json result.

With jQuery I am using onChange on a dropdown to call the php function and to get the results.

I think I have problems with the jQuery and json, but I have looked through multiple posts and cannot find a good answer.

Here is the code I am using.  How do I get to the json array?  I have tried data['ele'], data.ele, data[0] and all return undefined.

```
$('#itemDD').change(function(data){
      alert("Changing");
      askServer(function(data){
        alert("!" + data['retailListPrice']);
       //spin through the data and put the results in workingQuote
      });   
    });

function askServer(callback)
{
   var selItem = $('#itemDD').val();
   var strUrl = "getItemList.php?item=" + selItem + "&action=itemInfo";
   alert(strUrl);
    jQuery.ajax({
       url:strUrl, 
       success:callback, 
       dataType: "json" 
    });
}

 });
```

PHP

```
$sql="SELECT *
              FROM items
              WHERE modelNum='" . $selectedModel . "'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die("Error" . mysql_error());

        while(($resultArray[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) || array_pop($resultArray));
        echo json_encode($resultArray);
```

Comment: Make sure your provided url is ok, try absolute url like "http://example.com/getItemList.php?item=" + selItem + "&action=itemInfo" with "http://"

Comment: I gave it the full url, and still nothing.  I am updating with the php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You using array and mysql_fetch_assoc. So to get the data, use **data[0]['rowName']** or **data[0].rowName**

Answer (score 1):

try this (note: object/array format is diffrent in JS):

```
function askServer()
{
   var selItem = $('#itemDD').val();
   var strUrl = "getItemList.php?item=" + selItem + "&action=itemInfo";
   alert(strUrl);
   $.get(strUrl, function(data){
      alert(data.retailListPrice);
   });
}
```

Comment: I still get undefined. I threw the code in the askServer function into the change function of the #itemdd

Comment: post your json string. (did you set json header on php side.. not mandatory, but helps sometimes)

Comment: you could also try to `console.dir(data)` if you use firebug or some other console aware developer tools

Answer (score 1):

Inside change event just call the `askServer()` function and declare it outside of change event, like

```
$('#itemDD').change(function(data){
  //...
  askServer();   
});
```

and your `askServer()` function

```
function askServer()
{
        var selItem = $('#itemDD').val();
        var strUrl = "getItemList.php?item=" + selItem + "&action=itemInfo";
        $.get(strUrl, function(data){
            $.parseJSON(data); 
            alert(data.retailListPrice);
        });
 }
```